# Efficient way to find value that occurs the most times with each distinct other value, in large mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql table with approx 61 million rows.  The two columns i'm interested in for this question are "foo_type" and "foo_id".  What I want to do, is, for every distinct value of "foo_type", return the foo_id that occurs the most times.

So, my results will look like this:

```
foo_type  |  foo_id
-------------------
Banana    |  127321
Apple     |  59871
etc
```

etc, meaning "When foo_type is 'Apple', foo_id 59871 occurs more than any other value of foo_id."

Both of those columns are indexed with a single multi-column index (which covers just those two columns).

What is the most efficient way to do this?  thanks

EDIT:  I know in advance what all the possible values for foo_type are, if that helps.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry An MCRE is difficult in this case because it's all about how to deal with a very large dataset.  I could give a sample with 100 rows, but for that questions of efficiency will be irrelevant.  The difference between a good and bad answer for this will only really apply when the table size is very large.

Comment: There are many individuals within this community smart enough to naturally provide the most efficient solution (subject to constraints of cardinality, indexes, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a statistical concept called the *mode*. Some database have a built-in aggregate function for that (eg Oracle), but not MySQL.

You can work around this with aggregation and window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select foo_type, foo_id, count(*) cnt, 
        rank() over(partition by foo_type order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable 
) t
where rn = 1
```

This requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions:

```
select foo_type, foo_id, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
group by foo_type, foo_id
having count(*) = (
    select count(*)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.foo_type = t.foo_type
    group by t1.foo_id
    order by count(*) desc limit 1
)
```

Comment: thanks - I ran it on my local version which is about 1/200 the size of the production version (in terms of rows in this table) and it's still running after 15 mins.  I'm hoping there's a faster way...

Comment: @MaxWilliams . . . Neither of these queries should take 15 minutes on a table with 2 million rows (or even 60 million rows).  Something else might be slowing down your system.